# Recodificar variable que indica relaciones entre casos

Tags: r, tidyverse, reshape

Tengo unos datos de matrimonios en una comunidad que están registrados indicando las parejas mediante el uso del valores iguales en la variable **marriages**, de esta forma:

```
id      marriages
1235    1
143     NA
514     2
51435   NA
432     2
5       1
12      3
64      3
```

Los **NA** son personas solteras (y no personas casadas entre ellas). Me gustaría organizar los datos para que la variable **married_to** indique el valor para **id** del cónyuge de cada persona, de la siguiente forma:

```
id      married_to
1235    5
143     NA
514     432
51435   NA
432     514
5       1235
12      64
64      12
```

Esta es otra forma, pero que no me sirve por que se pierde el dato de los solteros:

```
marriages   spouse_1_id     spouse_2_id
1           1235            5
2           514             432
3           12              64
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df<-read.table(text= "id      marriages
1235    1
143     NA
514     2
51435   NA
432     2
5       1
12      3
64      3",header=T)

library(dplyr)

aux<-df%>%group_by(marriages)%>%
    summarise(married_to = id[1])%>%
    right_join(df)%>%
    filter(id!=married_to)

aux<-rbind(aux%>%select(marriages,id,married_to),
       aux%>%select(marriages,id=married_to,married_to=id))

aux$married_to[is.na(aux$marriages)]<-NA

aux

# A tibble: 8 × 3
  marriages    id married_to
      <int> <int>      <int>
1         1     5       1235
2         2   432        514
3         3    64         12
4        NA 51435         NA
5         1  1235          5
6         2   514        432
7         3    12         64
8        NA   143         NA
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es exactamente lo que buscaba.

Comment: Nicolas, si esta respuesta y la de patricio te han ayudado trata de votarlas a favor

Comment: Lo intenté pero "Necesitas 15 de reputación para votar positivamente las publicaciones."

Answer (score 0):

Si estás familiarizado con los paquetes de `tidyverse` puedes usar `pivot_wider` para reorganizar horizontalmente los datos:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  filter(!is.na(marriages)) %>% 
  group_by(marriages) %>%
  mutate(spouse=row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(values_from = id, 
              names_from = spouse,
              names_glue = "spouse_{spouse}_id")


# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   marriages [3]
  marriages spouse_1_id spouse_2_id
      <int>       <int>       <int>
1         1        1235           5
2         2         514         432
3         3          12          64
```

Detalle:

- Obviamente quitamos las filas sin `marriages` con `filter(!is.na(marriages))`
- Agrupamos por `marriages` y enumeramos cada cónyuge
- Aplicamos `pivot_wider` para expandir horizontalmente por `id`

Comment: Gracias. Este es un excelente complemento para la respuesta de @RolandoTamayo